# SSH Tunnel not working Unable to request a channel

Tags: php, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

I'm using PHP 5.6 with ssh2 extension to create SSH tunnel to a remote host, here is my code:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect("example.com", 22);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, "root", "123123")) {
if ($tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, '127.0.0.1', 1080)){
 //curl commands
 }
}
```

I can do some Linux commands working with ssh2_exec but can not create SSH tunnel with ssh2_tunnel, here the error logs:

> PHP Warning: ssh2_tunnel(): Unable to request a channel from remote
>   host

Anybody can give me some hints?

Note :

i have `AllowTcpForwarding yes` `GatewayPorts yes` inside

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: You may find help in this [PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57427).

Comment: thanks for your reply but i can`t find any solution with this url

Comment: If anything, it would be the comment on 2008-05-08 from "volkirik".

Comment: i cant understand you ? @zbee